# Exchange 2007 CCR: Logs not replicating to passive node partition

Tags: exchange-2007, failovercluster

In my environment I have setup Exchange 2007 in an CCR cluster, mirroring our main servers to a set of servers in passive mode. One of the partitions on the passive node that I have setup for the logs for Exchange 2007 has faulted, causing the partition to be unreadable. I have replaced the partition on the passive node, and setup the drive to mirror the one in active mode, but the logs are not replicating since the change.

Is there anyway to force the replication of the new drive for the logs to the new partition? Any idea why the logs are not replicating?

Any help or comments is appreciated, and thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you re-seeded the database on the passive node?

Comment: Hi Shane, this looks like the route I may need to take. Thank you for your support!

Comment: Hello Shane, I ran into another issue today with the passive node. I have not re-seeded yet, as I just found that 2 of the DB's are dirty. My question is, how do I proceed from here? Should I repair the DB's first, or should I re-seed? Any ideas?

Comment: Is it showing as dirty on the active node, or the passive one?

Comment: Just on the passive one. The active one says clean on all DB's. Also, I ran eseutil | M L on both nodes, and the logs are clean on both the active and passive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the active node's databases in a good state and the passive node's in a dirty state (and transaction logs not being copied and replayed), a re-seed is the appropriate next step.

It brings the passive node's database back to a working current baseline by copying the current data from the active node, and allows for the log copying to be started back up once that's complete.

Comment: Just the answer I was looking for, thanks again Shane!

Comment: Hey Shane, sorry, another question. To begin the re-seed, do I need to delete the DB files and transaction logs, leaving the folders empty? Also, any suggestions or references on how to proceed with the re-seeding process?

Comment: Nope, it should take care of the deletions for you.  Should be able to just click the "update storage group copy" thing in the sidebar when you have the storage group selected in the management console.

Comment: Since we are re-seeding, I would like to take the opportunity to increase the disk size where the DB's are located. Would it be possible to setup the new empty partition that is larger, and just start fresh? Or will I need to clone/copy the data over to the new disk/partition before re-seeding?

Comment: @yum_tacos4u You might need to create some of the directory structure, but a new clean partition should work just fine.